# unable to compile Maven project after switching to ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I've switched from Eclipse Indigo to ADT (version 22.3.0)
I compile a project using Maven through command line:

```
mvn clean install android:deploy android:run
```

The project compiled fine on my older system and I haven't changed it at all. Now when I import it to ADT I get the "already added" error during compilation:

```
...
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/sun/activation/registries/LineTokenizer;
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
[INFO] 1 error; aborting
...
```

I don't have X_src files I saw on other replies to this issue. I don't include any library in my `lib` folder either.
This happens even with basic POM file so I guess that ADT has changed the project somehow so it includes this `LineTokenizer` twice (I'm not including it anywhere), is this correct?
Does anyone know how to fix this, or to find where the multiple inclusions happen?

**Edit:**
the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Name</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.analytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>analytics</artifactId>
            <version>3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.facebook.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-android-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flurry</groupId>
            <artifactId>FlurryAgent</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>11</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: are you using this: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/ ?

Comment: I usually compile with the shell, but I have tried your link and got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADT will throw that error if its finds more than one instance of the same package but with different version number to them. Looking at your pom one of your dependencies is adding the `LineTokenizer` which is not up-to-date in comparison to the one supplied by the compiler. I would suggest you go to the Dependency Hierarchy using the maven POM Editor. This will allow you to select the extraneous dependency, which you can then exclude by right-clicking and selecting "Exclude Maven Artifact..." which will automatically add an `<exclusions>` element to your POM. This will remove the duplicate JAR from your Eclipse classpath and allow you to build you project. Do a `mvn clean install` after you done editing the POM though.

Comment: It appears one of the packages was using `javax.mail` which includes `Activation.LineTokenizer` excluding it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it helped you. Cheers!!